# How to find $\int{\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x-1}\right)^x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have tried to find $$\int{\biggl(\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x-1}\biggr)^x}dx$$ but I don't know how to do it, because it combines $u^x$ and $\dfrac{u}{v}$.

Comment: You are sure this has an elementary antiderivative? Where is this function from?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can't find an elementary antiderivative (and neither can I!)

Comment: This looks evil!

Comment: If this integral is from 2 to infinity, you can show it converges by using the integral test to make it into a series and then applying the root test.  I think that's probably what they want you to do.

Comment: I agree with @Parsa.  I would rewrite as a series.

Comment: @martini No. That's why I've asked. The function comes from my imagination…

Comment: I put the function into wolfram alpha to get a series representation, though I couldn't find any sequences on oeis.org that the numerators and denominators correspond to -- the series representation within its radius of convergence is in fact nice in the regard that it has rational numerators and denominators on the coefficients.

Comment: @Garmen1778 The problem with our imagination is that it can create problems which noone can solve ;)

Comment: Not evil, just improper (at $x=1$).

Comment: @Garmen1778 don't worry, if your bounty doesn't solve it, I will put a bounty on it...(checking to see how to do that)

Comment: I think it is the power of x which is what gets in the way with finding an explicit formula for this integral.

Comment: I don't think that it's even possible to find $\int{x^x}dx$ ...

Comment: For $\int x^x dx$ check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/how-to-solve-int-xxdx (But this one here looks complicated)

Comment: @KVRaman Both questions are mine.

Comment: @Garmen1778 there are some functions which ,(they say) cannot be integrated (without mathematica), this one from your imagination might belong to that set of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do...
$$\int f(x)^x\; dx=\int e^{x\ln f(x)}\; dx=\int e^{\alpha(x)}\; dx$$
where $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x-1}$

Comment: -1 Yes, you can, but does it lead you anywhere?

Comment: Mmm... It was a simple idea. (¬¬)

Comment: that logarithm isn't a neperian logarithm, expressed with $\ln f(x)$?

Comment: @Garmen1778 I have tried googling "neperian logarithms" couldn't find that term.  Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: Ups, sorry, I mean _natural logarithm_, expressed by $\ln f(x)$ or $\log_e f(x)$

Comment: @Garmen1778 is that how its said in another language?

Comment: @MaoYiyi Yes and no. **Yes** because here we say "neperian logarithm"(in our language) because the teachers taught us wrong. And **no** because the real definition of "neperian logarithm" is shown in this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napierian_logarithm

Comment: @Garmen1778 what! I searched wikipedia.org.  Also, which language are you talking about?

Comment: @MaoYiyi Spanish.

Comment: The cuestion about natural o decimal logarithm.. **Look** the exponential!!! (Edited notation)