# Integrating $x^x$ and getting a graph

Tags: integration, exponentiation

I've heard many times of functions that cannot be integrated. For example, $x^x$, which is the most common. But what I don't know is how could you, even if the graph has no equation, plot this integral. If anyone could give me a graph, I would be extremely pleased. Or at least, could you tell me how to graph it? Maybe in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: It is not true that $x^x$ cannot be integrated: where defined, the function is continuous, which means that it is Riemann integrable there. Instead, what you're probably thinking of is that $x^x$ has no elementary antiderivative, ie there is no elementary function $g$ such that $g'=x^x$.

Comment: It's false that $x^x$ "cannot be integrated", it's just that its integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Why are you interesetd in its graph?

Comment: The same way you graph the solution of any ordinary differential equation for which you are unable to write an explicit solution: solve numerically to some accuracy over some interval, say $0 < x < 3.$ You might as well take $y(0) = 0,$ it does no harm. I see, @Raymond has done that in an answer, with $0 < x < 2$

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as such, since it is specifically looking for a graph, which the other question did not provide.

Comment: Thanks @KReiser, but I already understand that x^x can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions. However, by taking your g'=x^x example, do you know how could I graph g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick picture of $\ x\mapsto \int_0^x t^t\;dt$

[image: plot]

I added the plot of the real and imaginary part of the integral in the complex plane $\ z\mapsto \int_0^z t^t\;dt\ $ with $z=x+iy$ (note the 'branch jump' on the negative axis $(-\infty,0)$).

[image: real part of the integral]

[image: imaginary part]

Comment: The values $I(0)=0,\ I(1)\approx 0.7834305107,\ I(2)\approx 2.833876745$ (I am computing the integral...)

Comment: These may be compared to the values provided in the famous ["Sophomore's Dream"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html).

Comment: Did you use Wolfram Mathematica?

And also, do you know how could I find the Taylor series of this graph? (I am kind of a beginner in these kinds of things)

Comment: @AnonymousPi: I used MuPad (recent versions of MatLab incorporates this CAS too) and asked directly to plot the numerical integral of $x^x$. You may rewrite $x^x=e^{x\ln(x)}$ to get the expansion proposed by Mhenni and then integrate every term $\int (x\ln(x))^n\;dx=$ as done by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28%28ln%28x%29*x%29%5En,x%29%20) (replace $n$ by small integers) but this is rather laborious and not really a Taylor series because of the $\log$ terms... The other [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx) should really help you more!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph of the function with Maple

Plot( $x^x$, $x=0..2$ );

[image]

The graph of the integral of $x^x$ using the truncated Taylor series

$$ x^x=1+\ln  \left( x \right) x+\frac{1}{2}\, \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) 
^{2}{x}^{2}+\frac{1}{6}\, \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}{x}^{3}+\frac{1}{
24}\, \left( \ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}{x}^{4}+O(x^5). $$

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wanted the graph of $x^x$, rather of its (presumably "inexistent") integral.

Comment: @leonbloy: Ty to read his post again. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the downvote for?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal downvote was me, because I think that Raymond's interpretation of the question was correct, so I think you're answering it incorrectly.

Comment: @BenMillwood: How?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: on second thoughts I've revoked the downvote on the grounds that there's enough confusion that it's probably a bad question rather than a bad answer, but it would be worth clarifying (I think that the questioner wants a plot of the integral of the function, rather than the function itself)

Comment: @BenMillwood: I already put the command plot$( x^x, x=0..2 )$, but you are right. I added that it is the graph of the function.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting thread for you: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=77605

Quote: The integral of x^x between 0 and 1 was calculated by Johann Bernoulli in 1697 using power series (not Euler). The proof appears in "Opera Omnia" vol. 3 (1697) pp. 376 - 381.