# How to calculate the integral of $x^x$ between $0$ and $1$ using series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

How to calculate $\int_0^1 x^x\,dx$ using series? I read from a book that 
$$\int_0^1 x^x\,dx = 1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\dots+(-1)^n\frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}}+\cdots$$ but I can't prove it. Thanks in advance.

P.S: I found some useful materials [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=77605&page=5) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407069/integrating-xx).

Comment: @Ｊ.M. duplication confirmed xD, I browsed through this site first but all I found was the second link in my question... thanks!

Comment: No problem; it just happened that I've seen the "sophomore's dream" asked a number of times on this site...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just write
$$x^x=e^{x\ln x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\ln x)^n}{n!}$$
and use that
$$\int_0^1(x\ln x)^n dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.$$

---

To show the last formula, make the change of variables $x=e^{-y}$ so that
$$\int_0^1(x\ln x)^n dx=(-1)^{n}\int_0^{\infty}y^ne^{-(n+1)y}dy,$$
which is clearly expressible in terms of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Nice, quick and simple, +1! Though you may want to elaborate on why the last equation is true.

Comment: thanks, the first equation looks nice!

Comment: @rbm: Do you mean the third one?

Comment: I see that you have already added the part about making the change of variables now ;). That was what I meant.