# How to prove that $\int^1_0 \frac{1}{x^x} dx = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^n} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

The task is: Prove, that

$$\int^1_0 \frac{1}{x^x} dx = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^n}$$

I completly don't have an idea, how to prove it. It seems very interesting, I will be glad if someone share a proof.

My initial thoughts are to use [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) to calculate the series, but I can't find a suitable function.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Comment: @Bitrex Thank You so much :-) You can change into answer to get points !

Comment: This has been asked here before.

Comment: I couldn't find, sorry @PeterTamaroff

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408503/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-xx-between-0-and-1-using-series

Comment: Those are the other version of the Sophomore's Dream, so not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Integrate
$$
x^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x\log(x))^n}{n!}
$$
using the substitution $u=-\log(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint,

$$\int^1_0 \frac{1}{x^x} dx = \int^0_{-1} \frac{1}{|x|^{|x|}} dx.$$

Also, use the geometrical interpretation of the integral with the observation that the subsequent terms in the series are getting small at more or less the same rate as $x^{-x}$ changes.