# how to integrate $\int\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^x}}}}_ndx$

Tags: integration, power-towers

how to integrate

> $$\int\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^x}}}}_ndx$$ $\color{red}{\text{or how to calculate  this integral  when its bounded}}$
>   $$\color{red}{\int_0^1\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^x}}}}_ndx}$$

Thanks in advance.

$\color{green }{\text{my attempt}}$ :
its easy to integrate $\int x^xdx$ $$\int{x^xdx} = \int{e^{\log x^x}dx} = \int{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k\log^k x}{k!}}dx=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\int x^k(\log x)^k\,dx \Rightarrow$$ substitute ${u = -\log x}$ then  $$ \int x^xdx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\int e^{u(k+1)}u^k\,du=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\int e^{u(k+1)}[(k+1)u]^k\,du.$$
Ii substitute  $t = (k+1)u$ and  $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\int e^tt^k\,dt $$ if i put bound for this integral we have $$\int _0^1x^xdx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\int_0^{\infty} e^tt^k\,dt =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)!}\frac{1}{(k+1)^k}\Gamma(k+1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$

$$\int_0^1\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}_ndx=\int_0^1e^{\log\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}_n}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1\biggl(\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}_{n-1}\biggr)^k(\log x)^k~dx$$

Comment: Can you integrate $x^x$?

Comment: have you considered logarithmic integration ?

Comment: Do you mean $((((x^x)^x)^x)^x)^x$ etc., as opposed to, say, $(x^x)^{(x^x)^{x^x}}$? (One must stipulate this sort of thing when it comes to exponentiation, it's not associative.)

Comment: Why so many downvotes?  This is a legitimate question, especially if someone does not know that the expression in question doesn't have an elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez:yes i can integrate $x^x$

Comment: if see this question please explain me why some user vote down or close my question ? is my question wrong ? or are there other reasons?

Comment: Maisam, I don't think your question is wrong . That there is no closed form for the integral should not be considered a reason for the question to be closed ...

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo, ok. Can you do the next one? :-)

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez:i edit my attempt to solve it?

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo Could you tell how do you compute the integral of $x^x$ and what is the result? I can only get [this series](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/408506/73025).

Comment: @O.L. :if put bound for this integral then we can compute it ?

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo Don't understand. Again: can you find $\int x^x dx$ in *explicit* form? (series doesn't count since it is even more difficult to compute than the original integral). If not, then "it is difficult to understand what is asked here". I vote to close.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I don't think that mathematicians can really ask what the point of a computation is... Sometimes it's not apparent until years down the road.

Comment: @O.L. Just because you can't compute something explicitly doesn't mean a question about it is bad.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo At your link I only find the very same series.

Comment: @O.L.: where? i don't ask or answer questions like it

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo Sorry, I've read "can" instead of "cant". But then I iterate my question. If you know that we cannot integrate $x^x$, what is the point of asking more complicated question containing $x^x$ as a special case?

Comment: @O.L.:no problem thanks .but you can assume this integral is bounded then  solve it

Comment: I don't even understand the expression. What are $n$, $t$, and $h$?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber, shouldn't it be $ x^{x^{x^{.\cdot^.}}} $? Using the grouping your second expression is equivalent to (x^x)^{x^{x + 1}} = x^{x^{x^{x+1} + 1}.

Comment: @dfeuer, I think the OP is trying to specify that the total amount of $x$s in the power tower is $n$. It's not a very concise explanation, which is probably why there are so many downvotes.

Comment: If you repeatedly use $e^x$’s Maclaurin series or [$\ln^n(x)$ Stirling number expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/), you can get an expansion of $n-1$ sums. It it straightforward enough that someone should have done it elsewhere already.

Answer (score 9):

If you replace $x$ by $x+1$ then you have $ \int (x+1)^{(x+1)^{...^{(x+1)}}} dx $ and the exponential-tower has an interesting power series, whose coefficients at the leading terms become constant in spite of increasing height $h$ (that $n$ in your formula) . Then you can integrate termwise to have a power series for the integral.
For instance, the tower of iteration height $h=6$ has the power series
$$  1 + x + x^2 + 3/2 \cdot x^3 + 7/3 \cdot x^4 + 4 \cdot x^5 + 283/40 \cdot x^6 + 4321/360 \cdot x^7 + O(x^8)$$ 
where the first terms up to $4 \cdot x^5$ stay constant for all higher iterations/exponential towers. (I do not know the range of convergence at the moment, maybe it is $ \small  \eta-1 \approx 0.4446... $ where $ \small \eta = \exp(\exp(-1))$ because of the range of convergence for the exponential-tower of infinite height).

The termwise integration gives
$$  x + 1/2 \cdot x^2 + 1/3 \cdot x^3 + 3/8 \cdot x^4 + 7/15 \cdot x^5 + 2/3 \cdot x^6 + 283/280 \cdot x^7 + O(x^8) $$ 
for the indefinite integral of the height $h=6$ exponential tower.

I get, using Pari/GP by the "explicite" integration (and substitution $x+1$ for $x$)

```
intnum(x=-1,0,(1+x)^(1+x)^(1+x)^(1+x)^(1+x)^(1+x))
%379 = 0.710658941398
```

which should be the correct value wrt to truncation to the shown digits. The use of the power series gives the value   $  0.710452400137$ which is inaccurate from the fourth digit (although I also applied Euler-summation for the diverging terms which have alternating signs), so the power series should be in principle usable also for higher exponential towers for small integration bounds and a more improved summation-procedure.

Unfortunately, there's a replacement $x \to (x+1)$ inside the integral and I do not know whether this is legitimate (I'm nearly illiterate with integration)

Comment: Sure, the substitution $x \to x+1$ is totally legitimate. $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_{a-1}^{b-1}f(x+1)\,\mathrm dx$. More generally: [integration by subsitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)

Answer (score 6):

MathWorld has already done for this.

Please see the formula (10) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html.

Comment: Nice find!  Wolfram never fails to surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution: $$\mathrm{\int{x^{x^{x^…}}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn^{n-2} Q\left(n,-ln(x)\right)+C}}$$

This works as a definite integral for $$\mathrm{e^{-\frac1e}\le x\le e^\frac 1e}$$

Here is my

> [**work**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168572/integral-over-domain-of-infinite-tetration-of-x-over-its-real-domain-from-0-to)

Comment: Note: You can get an expansion of $n−1$ sums using the [super root series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314712/calculating-the-nth-super-root-when-n-is-greater-than-2/4697772#4697772) near complex $z=1$ and [integral of inverse functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions). To be added. Additionally, if we could find the general derivative pattern [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703399/evaluating-fracdndtneat-et-as-a-single-series-to-extend-region-of), we could extend the convergence radius to include values closer to $z=0$.