# i cant find this integral $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm{dx} $$

Comment: Google "Sophomore's dream" for more about it.

Comment: here it is: $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm{d} x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\int_0^1{x^{-x}dx} = \int_0^1{e^{\log x^{-x}}dx} = \int_0^1{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^k\log^k x}{k!}}dx=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^1 (-1)^kx^k(\log x)^k\,dx $$ 
for more detail see here [how to integrate $\int\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^x}}}}_ndx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427816/how-to-integrate-large-int-xxxxxxnthxxxdx)

Answer (score 0):

The value is approximately 1.29129, as shown in this link:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=definite+integral+of+x^%28-x%29+from+0+to+1

Answer (score 0):

It's equal to 1 + 1/4 + 1/27 + 1/64 + .... +1/n^n ...

Comment: Predictably, I proved the similar result for x^x when I was a sophomore.