# Evaluating $\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{a(t-e^t)}$ as a single series to extend region of convergence for super root function

Tags: derivatives, roots, closed-form, tetration, lagrange-inversion

$\def\srt{\operatorname{srt}}$**Introduction:**

There is a [multiple series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314712/calculating-the-nth-super-root-when-n-is-greater-than-2/4697772#4697772) for the [**super root $\srt_n(z)$**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Super-root) valid near $0.7<|z|<1.4$. However, for around $0<|z|<1.3$, there is this expansion:

$$\sqrt[k]z_s=\srt_k(z)=z-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^{(n+1)t-e^t-\overbrace{ne^{t-e^{\dots}}}^{k-2\ “e^t”\text s}}\bigg|_{\ln(-\ln(z))}$$

Unfortunately, there is no obvious way to expand it as $k-1$ sums preserving convergence. A starting point is a method for finding a single series expansion for $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^{(n+1)(t-e^t)}$, when  $k=3$, or the derivatives in:
$$\ln(-\ln(\srt_3(e^z)))=\ln(-z)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^{n(t-e^t)}\right|_{\ln(-z)}$$

converging around $0<|z|<1.3$

**Attempt 1:**

Trying $\srt_3(z)$ via $e^y$ Maclaurin expansion and [changing summation order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876828/how-to-change-the-order-of-summation) gives:

$$\srt_3(z)=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(-1)^m m^{n-m} n^{m-2}}{(m-1)!(n-m)!}\ln^n(z)$$

converges for about $0.4<|z|<1.3$. If $n\gg m$, the region of convergence is a [bit larger](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28m-1%29+%28m%29%5E%28n-m%29+%28n%29%5E%28m-2%29%2F%28%28m-1%29%21+%28n-m%29%21%29+ln%28x%29%5E%28n%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C10%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C300%7D%5D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221.3%22), but not the original $0<|z|<1.3$:

[image]

**Attempt 2:**

Using [Stirling S2](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/20/02/), [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), and [factorial power $a^{(b)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^{n(t-e^t)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{m=0}^n s_{n-1}^{(k)}e^{-ne^t}e^{(k-m+n)t}\binom k nn^{(m)} (-n)^{k-m}$$

but this is not a single series expansion for:

$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{a(t-e^t)} =ae^{a(t- e^t)}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} (-1)^m a_m e^{am}$$

**Pattern**:

Creating a [table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BD%5Be%5E%28%28n%2B1%29+%28t-e%5Et%29%29%2C%7Bt%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D) and using the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C25%2C216&language=english&go=Search) shows that:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^{(n+1)(t-e^t)}=(-1)^{n+1} ne^{(n+1)(t-e^t)}\left((-1)^{n+1} (n+1)^{n-2}+(-1)^n ((n+2)^{n-1}-(n+1)^{n-1})e^t+?e^{2t}+\dots+(n+1)^{n-2} e^{n-1}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{t-e^t}=(-1)^n\left((-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}S_{n+1}^{(2)}e^t+(-1)^nS_{n+1}^{(3)}e^{2t}+(-1)^{n+1}S_{n+1}^{(4)}e^{3t}+\dots+e^{nt}\right)$$
**Question:**
What are methods for finding $\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{a(t-e^t)}$ as a single series so that a series expansion of $\srt_3(z)$ converges around $0<|z|<1.3$?

Comment: It might not exist ??

Comment: @mick What might not exist; the single series expansion for the coefficients or convergence around $0<|z|<1.3$?

Comment: I meant single series