# What is the function $f(x)=x^x$ called? How do you integrate it?

Tags: integration, reference-request, exponential-function, exponentiation

For real numbers $x > 0$, the function $f(x)=x^x$ seems pretty cool.

Is there a name for this function? It's obviously been studied before.

It grows faster than exponential functions and factorials but slower than [double exponentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function).

---

We can find its derivative by writing it as $$f(x) = x^x = e^{\ln x^x} = e^{x \ln x}$$

This lets us use the chain rule to get

$$f'(x) = e^{x \ln x} (\ln x + \frac{1}{x} \cdot x) =  x^x (1+ \ln x)$$

Since $x^x$ is never equal to zero, if we set $f'(x) =0$ we get $$1+ \ln x = 0$$

which gives

$$ x= e^{-1} = \frac{1}{e}$$

---

This (perhaps unsurprising?) appearance of $e$ might be enough to make this function interesting. At any rate, I tried to find its indefinite integral and failed miserably.

I guess my question is partially a reference request ... where can I read more about $x^x$?

Comment: I actually was wondering about that function as well. It turns out that there is no elementary antiderivative, at least according to wolfram Alpha

Comment: Maybe try to work with $e^{x\log x}$'s Taylor series? Just an idea, I didn't look at it closely yet.

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx) may be of help

Comment: I know them as a second tetration: ${}^1x=x$ is first tetration. ${}^2x = x^x$ is a second tetration. While ${}^3x = x^{(x^x)}$ is a third tetration.

Comment: See [Tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream), [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)), and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My favorite paper about $x^x$ is [The $x^x$ Spindle](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2691469), which appeared in Mathematics Magazine back in 1996.  The main idea is to visualize the fact that we can write it as
$$x^x = e^{x (\ln(x)+2k\pi i)}.$$
Note that for each choice of $k$, we get a different branch of the logarithm.  Given any real number $x$, most of these branches will be complex valued.  Thus, we can plot a curve in 3D.  For $k=0$ (i.e., the principal branch), it looks something like so:

[image]

If we use more branches simultaneously, we get something like so:

[image]

If you plot the standard graph of $y=x^x$ including the values of $(p/q)^{p/q}$ for $p$ negative and $q$ odd and positive.  Thus the graph might look something like so.

[image]

From the complex perspective, the dots arise as spots where one of the spiral threads punctures the $x$-$z$ plane.

---

As far as integration goes, Mathematica (which I used to make the images), doesn't return a value for the antiderivative - I'd be shocked if it can be expressed in closed form.  Nonetheless, the integral can be expressed as a series (as in UserX's answer) and there's the fabulous fact, known as [the sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) that
$$\int_0^1 x^x \, dx = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n)^{-n},$$
which was mentioned in the comments by Lucian.

Also, the integral can certainly be evaluated numerically.  If we define 
$$F_k(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x e^{x (\ln(x)+2k\pi i)} \, dx,$$
Then the graphs of the resulting functions look something like so:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you know series, as the integral of that cannot be expressed in elementary functions(if you let any function then you can just define $\mathfrak{F}(x)=\int_0^x t^t\,\mathrm{d}t$), then;

$$\int x^x\mathrm{d}x=\int e^{x\log x}\mathrm{d}x=\int e^{\log x^x}\mathrm{d}x\;\;\stackrel{\text{series for }e^x}{=}\;\;\int \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n\log^n x}{n!}\mathrm{d}x$$