# The domain of $x^x$?

Tags: real-analysis

This one looks simple, but apparently there is something more to it. 
$$f{(x)=x^x}$$
I read somewhere that the domain is $\Bbb R_+$, a friend said that $x\lt-1, x\gt0$...

I'm really confused, because i don't understand why the domain isn't just all the real numbers.
According to any grapher online the domain is $\Bbb R_+$.
Any Thoughts on the matter?

Can someone explain what am I missing?

Comment: What would $f(-1/2)$ be?

Comment: And I'm not sure how your friend would make sense of $f(-3/2)$ either

Comment: Write it as $x^x = e^{x\ln(x)}$ not it is easy to determine the domain.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven, I think if $n$ were odd, you would be fine.  Domain should not include $x=\frac{-1}{2n}$, yes?  So I suppose there is a class of negative rational numbers you could use for the domain, but certainly not all $x<-1$, as in the comment from Omnomnomnom.

Comment: differntiate $x^x$ with respect to $x$ in the case of real $x$ must be $x>0$

Comment: Yes, @JohnMolokach, you are correct...i should have read the part in the OP's comment where $x<-1$...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, why should the derivative define the domain of a function?

Comment: @m_gnacik but your equation is only true for $x>0$ while the LHS is defined from **some** negative values.  See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cftrtgyi75.

Comment: Even though one might be able to play around with odd roots versus even roots and so on, given that the tag is real-analysis, the comment of @m_gnacik seems to give the correct answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I agree with you, which is why I elaborated on this in my answer below.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041559/what-is-the-function-fx-xx-called-how-do-you-integrate-it/1041588#1041588) provides a plot of the graph in the real case and indicates how it arises as a slice of a collection of complex graphs clearly indicating the domain from kamil09875's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split it into cases:

1. When $x=p/q$ where $p\in \mathbb Z,q\in\mathbb N_{>1},p\ne0,\gcd(p,q)=1$, then:
   $$x^x=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^\frac{p}{q}=\sqrt[q]{\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^p}$$

   - when $p<0$ then 
      $$x^x=\sqrt[q]{\left(-\frac{q}{|p|}\right)^{|p|}}$$
     if $p$ is even, then $\left(-\frac{q}{|p|}\right)^{|p|}$ is positive, otherwise it's negative and the root doesn't exist for even $q$.
   - when $p>0$ then 
      $$x^x=\sqrt[q]{\left(\frac{|p|}{q}\right)^{|p|}}$$
     and $\left(\frac{|p|}{q}\right)^{|p|}$ is always positive.
2. When $x\in\mathbb Z$ the value $x^x$ always exist except $x=0$.
3. When $x$ is irrational then the only way to define $x^x$ is $$x^x=\exp(x\ln x)$$ and for real numbers we have $x>0$.

Summarizing, $x^x$ exist for all

- $x\in\mathbb R_+$
- $x\in\mathbb Z_-$
- $x\in\left\{ -\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb Q\colon p,q\in\mathbb N_+ \land \gcd(p,q)=1\land q\text{ is odd}\right\}$

**Why we don't see the negative part of the plot**

1. Technical reason: $x^x$ in programs is usually defined as `exp(x*log(x))` and the function `log(x)` is not defined for negative `x`.
2. Mathematical reason: set of negative $x$ which $x^x$ exists for is countable. Countable many points is not enough to form a curve.

This function may be [plotted with points for negative $x$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/45004tcvxg).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your mathematics background is, but the function
$f(x)=x^x$ is defined for $\mathbb{R}_+$ as well as a countably infinite set of rational values in $\mathbb{Q}_-$.  For example, we can find $f(-\frac n3)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  In fact, I cannot with confidence write down the entire set of negative values in the domain but any $x=\frac n {1-2n}$ will work for starters.

Some textbooks won't include the negative values, because they form a countable set of numbers that has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: …and because the resulting function is _extremely_ discontinuous on that countable set.