# Could you solve $x↑^n2=x↑^m2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, tetration, power-towers

As my title asks, could you solve $x^2=2^x$?

But that's the worrisome part, as I noticed $x↑^n 2=x↑^m 2$ and $2↑^p x=2↑^q x$ will always have a solution at $x=2$.  However, there is bound to be at least another solution.

For example:$$2x=x^2$$has a solution at $x=2,0$.

And $x^2=2^x$ has a solution at $x=2,4,-z$ where $z$ is some hard to determine value.

But I question $2^x=x^x$ having more solutions than just $x=2$.

$x^2=x^x$ appears to have solutions at $x=1,2$ and possibly a negative solution as well.

So what can one say about these solutions other than $x=2$ and some other number?

I've also noticed $2↑^n1=2$ as well.

Which makes my also wonder how odd $2$ is when it comes to higher towers.

And $1$, as that solution arises often.

Due to the confusion in what kind of answer I want, I will make a clarification.$$x↑^12=x\cdot x=x^2$$$$x↑^22=x^x=^2x$$$$x↑^32=^xx=f_2(x)$$$$x↑^42=f_x(x)=g_2(x)$$And so it goes...

Comment: $x^x$ for $x$ negative non-integer is not really defined.

Comment: You could use approximation methods or the Lambert W function to solve for such values though.  And I believe they point towards a possible negative number

Comment: "Possibly"  I haven't really checked.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66166.html will help.

Comment: I also know that.  In fact, I've looked at that in the past (before learning about Lambert W and calculus) but it doesn't do anything for things beyond $x^x$.

Comment: What equation do you want to solve? You are explicitly asking about $2^x=x^2$, get an answer, then say you altready knew that. Then you go on about this and that and more equations.

Comment: I've changed my title to match my question.

Comment: For $x^2-x^x$ the newton-algorithm finds the following roots in the square region of complex plane $-5-5i,5-5i,5-5i,5+5i$ :                       $$ [-0.50362 \pm 0.42656*I] \\
[1.0000] \\
[2.0000] \\
[3.5449 \pm 3.2644*I] \\
[4.4357 \pm 5.3698*I] \\
$$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yes, but it also finds an infinite amount of solutions if you extend it to any $x$ values allowed.

Comment: Oh very well -- I didn't check that

Comment: @GottfriedHelms well, it is a direct result of the lambert W function's infinite branches for $x\ne0$ in $W_k(x)$.

Comment: Upps, I didn't think of that roots as of different branches of the logarithm /exponentiation. The latter is of course another thing and I know that this gives infinitely many solutions. But frankly: I just did a couple of tests using the Newton-iteration to get an overview. No deep discussion/ analysis intended from my side ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have probably surmised, $x \uparrow^n 2 = x \uparrow^m 2$ and $2 \uparrow^p x = 2 \uparrow^q x$ have solutions at $x=1$ and $x=2$.  If $m=n$ or $p=q$ then of course any $x$ will be a solution; if $m \neq n$ or $p \neq q$ then there are no other solutions.

First, I will prove the following useful theorems:

Theorem. For $a \ge 2$ and $b \ge 1$

a. $a \uparrow^b c > a\uparrow^b (c-1)$ for $c \ge 2$.

b. $a \uparrow^b c > c$ for $c \ge 1$.

Proof: By double induction on $b,c$.  For $b=1$, we have $a^c = a * a^{c-1} > a^{c-1}$, and it is well known that $a^c \ge 2^c \ge c+1$. (Use the binomial theorem for example.)

For $c=1$, we have $a \uparrow^b 1 = a > 1$.

Assuming the theorem for $b$, and for $b+1$ and $c$, we will prove it for $b+1$ and $c+1$.  Observe that

$$a\uparrow^{b+1}(c+1) = a\uparrow^b (a\uparrow^{b+1}c) > a\uparrow^{b+1} c$$

which proves part a.  For part b, observe that $a\uparrow^{b+1}(c+1) > a\uparrow^{b+1} c > c$, so $a\uparrow^{b+1}(c+1) > c+1$, as desired.

Corollary. Given a fixed $a \ge 2$ and $b \ge 1$, $a \uparrow^b c$ is an increasing function of $c$.

The corollary follows directly from the theorem part a.

Theorem 2. Given $a,c \ge 2$ and $b \ge 1$, $a\uparrow^b c \ge c+2$.

Proof: By induction on $b$.

If $b=1$, then$a^c \ge 2^c \ge c+2$.

Assume the theorem for $b$.  Then $$a\uparrow^{b+1} c = a\uparrow^b(a\uparrow^{b+1}(c-1)) \ge a\uparrow^b c \ge c+2$$

Now we can address the original equations.  Observe that for $a \ge 2$, $b \ge 1$, $c \ge 3$,

$$a\uparrow^{b+1} c = a\uparrow^b(a\uparrow^{b+1}(c-1) \ge a\uparrow^b(c+1) > a\uparrow^b c$$

so that $a\uparrow^b c$ is an increasing function of $b$; in particular, $2\uparrow^p x =2\uparrow^q x$ has no solutions for $p \neq q$ and $x \ge 3$.

If $a \ge 3$, $b \ge 1$, $c = 2$,

$$a\uparrow^{b+1} 2 = a\uparrow^b a > a\uparrow^b 2$$

so in this case again $a\uparrow^b 2$ is an increasing function of $b$; in particular, $x \uparrow^n 2 = x \uparrow^m 2$ has no solutions for $m \neq n$ and $x \ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you for putting a lot of time and effort into your answer, as it certainly is more formal than simply noting things.  I will have to point out the following: $x$ may be complex, as we see in the solution to $x^2=x^x$, it is more than $x=1,2$, along with an infinite amount of complex solutions.  Of course, I don't expect an answer concerning these complex solutions as they are not currently definable.  So this answer satisfies.

Answer (score 2):

For $x^2=2^x$ you have

$$x=2^{x/2}$$
$$1=x2^{-x/2}$$
$$-\tfrac12\ln(2)=-\tfrac12\ln(2)xe^{-\ln(2)x/2}$$
$$-\tfrac12\ln(2)x=W(-\tfrac12\ln(2))$$
$$x=-\frac{2W(-\tfrac12\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}$$

For $2^x=x^x$ there's a solution $x=2$ and $x=0$ (taking $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x$). For negative $x$, $x^x$ is not well defined, but there seem to be the only solution $x=-2$. For the plot you can check my [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557042).

Comment: XD... I already know that.  I just want to see what is up with higher powers like $x↑^52=x↑^62$.  Thank you though

Comment: I also prefer to leave the one half fraction in the denominator along with the negative as a preference so that it takes the shape$$x=\frac{W[f(u)]}{f(u)}$$

Comment: What is W here ?

Comment: @Anjan3 it's the Lambert W-function

Comment: @GottfriedHelms yes, $-2$ is a solution for $2^x=x^x$ and it doesn't mean that $4=1/4$.