# The general solution of $x^a = a^x$ for real $a >0$

Tags: exponential-function, roots, lambert-w

What are the roots of
$$f(x) = x^a - a^x$$
for real $a > 0$?

- Case 1: For $0 < a < 1$ there is 1 solution, $x=a$.
- Case 2: For $1\le a < e$ there are 2 solutions: $x=a$ and $[x>a]$.
- Case 3: For $a > e$ there are 2 solutions: $x=a$ and $[x < a]$.

if we let b = a^(1/a). x = b^^ [use mathematica for tetration]
or using the basic operators, 
x = b^(b^(b^...))...)
for a > e, this solves for the non-simple root < a 
but for a < e it solves for  x = a
i am looking for a similar solution for a < e

Answer (score 4):

For $a\neq 1$ $x^a=a^x$ is equivalent to 
$$x=a^{\frac{x}{a}}\\
xa^{-\frac{x}{a}}=1\\
xe^{-\frac{\ln a}{a}\cdot x}=1\\
(-\frac{\ln a}{a}\cdot x)e^{-\frac{\ln a}{a}\cdot x}=-\frac{\ln a}{a}\\
-\frac{\ln a}{a}\cdot x=W(-\frac{\ln a}{a})\\
x=-\frac{aW(-\frac{\ln a}{a})}{\ln a}$$
using [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Note that this function is actually multivalued for negative arguments, so it includes both the trivial solution $x=a$ and the other, nontrivial one. One shouldn't expect to be able to solve for $x$ using only elementary functions.

Comment: wojowu, do you consider tetration to be an elementary function?

Comment: @phlexicon No, I don't. I follow (fairly standard) convention that elementary functions are ones which can be constructed using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and handful of other "basic" functions, listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Comment: my solution for a > e uses tetration merely as a convenience allowing a more concise expression. i can express it using only the basic operators +,*,/, exponentiation. so while unexpected it does exist for a > e. it is the domain 1 to e that i have found unyielding to a solution.

Comment: @phlexicon How does your solution look like?

Comment: let b = a^(1/a).  x = b^^ or using the basic operators, x = b^(b^(b^...))...)

Comment: for a > e it gives the non simple root but for a < e it gives the simple root

Comment: @phlexicon For $a = 4 > \mathrm{e}$, the solution $x = 2$ is simple, right? :-)

Comment: Isn't that function multivalued for positive arguments as well?

Comment: @SimpleArt It is assuming we work with complex numbers. I've assumed we are are working with real numbers, and then $W$ is single-valued for positive arguments.

Comment: Wojowu, you can allow $a=1$ in your solution if you convert your final answer into $e^{W(f(x))}$

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a complete answer, but an example showing that **two** (in some circumstances exact) solutions do actually exist.

Let $a := 2$. Then
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
  x := 2 &\Rightarrow& x^2 =& 4 &= 2^x, \\
  x := 4 &\Rightarrow& x^2 =& 16 &= 2^x. \tag{*}
\end{array}
$$

Let $a := 4$. Then
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
  x := 2 &\Rightarrow& x^4 =& 16 &= 4^x, \tag{*} \\
  x := 4 &\Rightarrow& x^4 =& 256 &= 4^x.
\end{array}
$$

The solutions (*) arise from the symmetry in the equation. I conjecture that, if more such examples exist, powers of $2$ might play a role.

Comment: This is related to a similar question of mine:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582600/could-you-solve-x%e2%86%91n2-x%e2%86%91m2