# Prove $a^n \ge n^a$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, lambert-w

I was reading a little from a book on Real Analysis (which I'm not that far into yet), and I came across a problem: prove $2^n \ge n^2, \forall n >4\in \Bbb N$. Though "challenging", I was able to prove this problem with induction without much struggle. I then considered proving this same problem for any integer '$a$' in replace of $2$. I.e. prove:

$$a^n \ge n^a$$

where $a,n \in \Bbb N$. The first thing I decided to do was look for the smallest '$n$' that would actually work for a given '$a$'. I did this by simply solving for $n$:

$$\begin {align}
a^n \ge& n^a\\
n^{1 \over n} \ge& a^{1 \over a}\\
{1 \over n}\ln n \ge& \ln a^{1 \over a}\\
\ln n e^{-\ln n} \ge& \ln{a^ {1 \over a}}\\
-\ln n e^{-\ln n} \ge& -\ln{a^ {1 \over a}}\\
-\ln n \ge& W_0(-\ln{a^{1 \over a}})\\
n \ge& e^{-W_0(-\ln a^{1 \over a})}
\end {align}$$

where $a \in \Bbb N$ and $W_0(x)$ is Lambert's $W$ Function.

My first question is: "Is this a valid constraint to put on $n$?", and my second and third questions are: "Is this a valid method for proving the inequality for values of $n$ larger than or equal to what I just derived? And if it isn't, how do I prove it using induction?"

Comment: So does this "duplicate" imply that my method was ok?

Comment: Your form is essentially the same, since $e^{-W(z)}=W(z) / z\,$. Yet another answer where the same is derived is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590933/291201).

Comment: I suppose so. Sorry for the duplicate. :/

Comment: To make this point clear, there is nothing negative towards you, or the question itself, in the "duplicate" flag. That's just the quickest way to point out the existing answers. And there is no need for *you* to be "sorry" about it. If anything, MSE could do a better job at locating potential duplicates at the time of the post, and/or listing them under the `related` column on the right-hand side (which, in this case, it did not and does not).

Answer (score 0):

Not by induction, but one way to go about it.
Note that
$$ \left(\frac{t}{\ln (t)} \right )' = \frac{(-1 + \ln(t))}{\ln^2(t)}$$
Thus  $t /\ln t$ is  strictly increasing for $t > e$.
Therefore, for $a,t > e$ and $t \ge a$
$$ \frac{t}{\ln t} \ge \frac{a}{\ln a}$$
$$\Rightarrow a^{t} \ge t^{a} $$
and for $a,t >e$ and $t < a$, we have
$$ \frac{t}{\ln t} < \frac{a}{\ln a}$$
$$\Rightarrow a^{t} < t^{a} $$
Thus for intgers $a,n \ge 3$, if $n\ge a,$ we have $a^n \ge n^a$ and if $n < a$, we have $a^n <n^a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be real. Take logs. Your inequality translates to $$n\ln{a}>a\ln{n}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad
\ln{a}/a>\ln{n}/n$$
The function $\ln{x}/x$ is greatest when $x=e$, and decreases monotonically on either side, so the inequality is satisfied if $e<a<n$ or $n<a<e$. The remaining case is if $e$ lies between $a$ and $n$.  You could then just look at the graph of $\ln{x}/x$. Or I suppose you could use Lambert W.