# How should I solve this quesiton on Integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I want to answer this question:
If
$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} n^k \int_0^{1/n} x^{x+k-1} dx = f(k)
$$
for $k \in \mathbb N$, what is
$$
\left[\frac{1}{f(5)}\right],
$$
where square brackets denote the greatest integer function (i.e., ceil)?

I tried it by substituting $t = x + k - 1$, but got stuck.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx

Comment: since $x$ is small on the whole range of integration we might taylor expand the integrand. To first order we get 
$$
f(k)/n^k\sim \int^{1/n}_0x^{k-1}=\frac{1}{n^{k}k}
$$
can you conclude?

Comment: Furthermore it is simple to show that higher order terms are $\mathcal{O}(n^{k+1})$ and the correct limit is indeed given by the above approximation

Answer (score 10):

As innisfree suggested in his comment, this is an ideal case for the squeeze theorem.

Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $x \in [0,1/n] \subseteq [0,1]$ so the larger the exponents, the smaller the number. Thus

$$\int_0^{1/n}x^{1/n + k - 1} \,dx < \int_0^{1/n} x^{x+k-1} \,dx < \int_0^{1/n} x^{0+k-1} \,dx$$

$$\frac{1}{(1/n+k)n^k} < \int_0^{1/n} x^{x+k-1} \,dx < \frac{1}{kn^k}$$

$$\frac{1}{1/n+k} < n^k\int_0^{1/n} x^{x+k-1} \,dx < \frac{1}{k}$$

and taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we find that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^k\int_0^{1/n} x^{x+k-1} \,dx = \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: squeeze theorem is always nice (+1)

Comment: As simple as can be, well done!

Comment: I made the comment, then changed my mind/confused myself and deleted it! Long week ... So it's not there now...

Answer (score 1):

Try $y= nx $. The integral simplifies,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \left(\frac yn \right)^{\frac yn} y^{k -1} dy =
\int_0^1 y^{k -1} dy = 1/k
$$
The first factor in the integrand gives 1 when we take the limit. Thus we find $1/f(5) = 5$.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer!

Comment: You should add an argument explaining why you may interchange the limit and the integral, otherwise the answer is incomplete (and possibly wrong).