# Can the integral $\int x^x \, \mathrm{d}x$ be evaluated?

Tags: calculus, integration

It's obvious that $\dfrac{d(x^x)}{dx}=x^x (1+\ln x)$, then what about its integral?
Special functions can be used if this integral can't be evaluated with simple functions, e.g. Gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ or Lambert W-function $W(x)$.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-the-integral-displaystyle-int-x-x-mathrm-d-x-be-evaluated

Comment: Unlikely that this hasn't been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, this function can not be integrated in terms of elementary functions as shown by @shrey's comment. So there is no "simple" answer to your question, unless you are willing to consider a series approximation:

$$\int{x^xdx} = \int{e^{\ln x^x}dx} = \int{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k\ln^k x}{k!}}dx$$  Hope it helps.