# $\int_{0}^{x} t^tdt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, closed-form

Is there a closed analytical expression for $I(x)$ with $x,t \in \mathbb{R_+}$ and

$$I(x) = \int_{0}^{x} t^tdt$$ 
?

I suppose this integral is some classic example for a function without analytic closed form. I have searched this site the web and testet several CA systems but could not find a result.

Question 2: In case there is not, is there way to show this?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) may be relevant.

Comment: $t^t=e^{t\ln t}$

Comment: @Olba12: thats entirely clear to me, I just did not see before Zuzub's comment how this contributes to the solution.

Comment: Please see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx

Comment: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Comment: @JJacquelin: So its $Sphd(1;x)$ !

Comment: Yes, it is. Insofar this special function becomes referenced as a standard function.