# Integrate $\int x^x dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have proceeded as follows:
$$I = \int x^x dx = \int \sum \frac {(x \log x)^k}{k!} dx = \sum \frac {\Gamma [k+1, -(k+1) \log x]}{(-1)^k(k+1)^{k+1}k!} + C$$
But I am unable to go further to get rid of the series form and have a closed form expression.
Please don't get confused with another post on the same topic . I am just trying to go a little deeper. Approximate closed expressions are well invited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding $\int x^xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx)

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe there _is_ a closed form expression?

Comment: There is indeed a closed form but only for the definite integral from $0$ to $1$ known as ["Sophomore's Dream"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). Furthermore search for `"x^x"[integration]` on MSE and you will find various post about your integral. Maybe there is something useful within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed form for this integral was proposed in the document :
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function
$$\text{Sphd}(\alpha\:;\:x)=\int_0^x t^{\alpha t}dt$$
Thus
$$\int_0^x t^t dt=\text{Sphd}(1\:;\:x)$$
$$\int x^x dx=\text{Sphd}(1\:;\:x)+\text{constant}$$
The document referenced above provides a lot of relationships, properties and related infinite series.

See also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Answer (score 2):

You arrived at
$$\int { { x }^{ x } } dx=\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ \int { \frac { { { x }^{ n }\left( \ln {x} \right) }^{ n } }{ n! } } dx}$$ which is equal to $$=\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { 1 }{ n! } \int { { x }^{ n } } { \left( \ln { x } \right) }^{ n } dx }$$
Consider $u = {\left(\ln {x} \right)}^{n} $, $dv = {x}^{n} dx $.

Now, you should use the integration by parts to complete the exercise.

Comment: ToposLogos I have already done all that to arrive at the series expression . But now I think there may be at least some approximate closed form expression for that.