# Integral Question x^x

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

How do I show that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^{x}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^k}$. Also, how do I show that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{ln(x)} dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}) - ln(k)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding $\int x^xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx) (in particular [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141423/631494) answer)

Comment: Contest math is definitely an inappropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

Convert x^-x to the taylor series by $$x^{-x}=e^{-xlnx}$$ and then integrating the series from zero to 1.
  $$\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-xlnx)^n}{n!}$$
Hope this has helped and put you in the right direction!